# Qual é a diferença entre Activity e View no Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Qual é a diferença entre `Activity` e `View` no Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Segundo a [documentacao](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> Uma Activity é uma ação especifica, singular, que um usuario pode fazer. Quase todas as Activities interagem com o usuario, entao a classe Activity cuida de criar a janela pra voce na qual voce pode integrar a interface do usuario (UI) com setContentView(View).

Em outras palavras, a Activity é como se fosse a unidade base de uma tela em um app Android.

Já a [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> Esta classe representa o bloco basico de construcao pra componentes da interface visual do usuario.  Uma view ocupa uma area retangular na tela e é responsavel por "desenhar" a si mesma e tratar eventos.

Você deve conhecer Herança, no Java os elementos que você arrasta e solta pra tela como TextView, EditText, ImageView, etc, **herdam** dessa classe base View, que tem um conjunto de atributos e metodos pra controlar esses componentes na tela.

Usando uma analogia, a **Activity** é a estrutura da casa e a **View** são os móveis e tudo que adiciona funcionalidade a essa estrutura.

Tentei traduzir a documentacao e explicar com minhas palavras, espero que tenha ficado mais claro! Quem tiver mais informacoes por favor comente ou edite :)