# O que é uma View no Android?

Tags: java, android

Os componentes visuais do Android como `EditText`, `Button` e outros, possuem os [Listeners](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236123/27190) para tratar eventos disparados por ações efetuadas por usuários.

Sendo assim, no método correspondente ao evento, é necessário sempre passar uma `View` como parâmetro. Veja um pequeno exemplo:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoMsg);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        EditText edtMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMsg);

        String msg = edtMsg.getText().toString();

        if (!msg.trim().isEmpty()) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Digite uma mensagem!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Repare que no método `onClick()` a variável `view` nem foi utilizada, e no método `findViewById()` esta buscando um `EditText` que talvez possa ser uma View.

É neste ponto que surgem as minhas dúvidas em relação a classe `View` e a View no Android.

## Dúvidas

1. Eu sempre vi uma View como a representação de toda a interface gráfica de uma aplicação, entretanto, neste caso a View não parece assumir este papel, então eu gostaria de saber o que é uma `View` no Android?
2. Qual é a finalidade da classe `View`?
3. Qual é a importância desta classe em relação aos componentes visuais
   do Android?

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, parece ser só um controle de tela. No GWT tem o `Widget`, no TotalCross tem o `Control` e o AWT tem o `Component`. Um negócio genérico que pode ser plotado na tela

Comment: [`AWT Component`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a diferença entre Activity e View no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184771/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-activity-e-view-no-android)

Comment: O parâmetro `view` no caso é o `Button`. Você poderia fazer cast dele para o tipo `Button` e trabalhar com ele (por exemplo, mudando a cor do botão quando este fosse clicado).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> O que é uma `View` no Android ?

A definição concreta é mesmo classe, como se pode ver no [código fonte do android](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View) :

```
public class View implements Drawable.Callback, KeyEvent.Callback, AccessibilityEventSource {
    ...
```

Esta classe representa na verdade um elemento da tela. É uma peça da interface gráfica que o usuário vê. Ocupa uma area retangular e é responsável por desenhar o componente na tela assim como responder aos seus eventos.

A `View` é apenas a classe base de uma hierarquia de classes para os vários tipos de elementos visuais que vemos nos demais aplicativos, tais como o `Button` ou `EditText` que indicou.

Olhando para um diagrama dessas classes fica ainda mais claro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A finalidade da hierarquia é poder dar comportamento e aspeto visual mais especifico a sub-classes de `View`.

> Qual é a finalidade da classe View ?

Em termos gerais já respondi no ponto acima, e em relação ao código que apresentou:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
```

O `view` refere o elemento que foi clicado, que neste caso corresponde ao botão onde foi definido o `OnClickListener`, este:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoMsg);
```

Isto permite-lhe fazer coisas mais especificas como registar o mesmo `listener` em vários botões e dentro do `listener` descobrir qual deles foi clicado consultando o `id` através da `view`, com `view.getId()`.

Na generalidade dos casos este parâmetro acaba por não ser utilizado.

> Qual é a importância desta classe em relação aos componentes visuais
>   do Android?

Esta classe representa os componentes visuais!

[Documentação para a classe View do Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Da para ver que a classe View é bastante importante para os componentes visuais do Android, e a mesma tem [muitas linhas de código](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) xP

Comment: @gato 26485 linhas de código(incluindo comentários) para ser mais preciso!

Answer (score 4):

Como diz a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), a `View` é a classe mais básica para construção de componentes visuais dos simples aos mais complexos. Em poucas palavras, a `View` é um retângulo que responde às interações do usuário.

O `EditText`, `Button`, `ConstraintLayout` e todos os outros componentes visuais no Android são filhos da classe gráfica mais básica, `View`.

O termo *view*, no contexto Android, ainda pode-se referir à interface gráfica como um todo, porém não se deve confundir com a classe `android.view.View`.

A classe `View` ainda herda de outra classe mais básica ainda, a [`Object`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html), que é a base para todas as outras classes. Ainda que não herde explicitamente, se você criar uma classe nova, as instâncias dos objetos dessa classe terão os métodos (`toString`, `equals`, etc) de `Object`.

De forma simples e representativa, temos:

[image]

Alguns links que achei interessante a leitura:

- [Caelum: Herança, reescrita e polimorfismo](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/#7-1-repetindo-codigo)
- [Android Developers: android.view.View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)
- [Android Developers: java.lang.Object](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 4):

> O que é uma **View**?

Nada mais e nada menos que uma simples caixa rectangular que responde às ações do usuário.

> Qual é a finalidade da **Classe View**

Ela representa os blocos onde serão construídos os componentes da interface. Por exemplo, essa é classe base para os *widgets*, que por sua vez, são usados para criar as UI com componentes interativos, tais como os botões, campos de texto e outros.

> Qual é a importância desta classe?

Muito importante, sem ela não temos nenhum componente visual :).