# Chamar método com parâmetro do tipo View, em outro método

Tags: java, android

Exemplos de um método que exige uma `View`

```
public void lista(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void botaoAbrir (View view) { 
      Intent i = new Intent(this, NovoRegistro.class); 
      startActivity(i); 
}
```

Gostaria de chamá-los dentro de `onCreate()` ou algum outro método que não necessite de `View`.

A forma que tentei e funcionou:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lista(new View(this));
}
```

**Mas a questão é, está correto ?**

Pode ser usado assim sem problemas ? Quais outras formas ?

É vantagem eu criar uma `View` para a classe, e sempre chamá-la ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos pensar um pouco... Se o método solicita uma `View` como parâmetro, é porque o processamento realizado neste método é inerente à `View` que será repassada.

Como sabemos uma `View` é um elemento que está na tela do aplicativo (leia [O que é uma View no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237870/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-view-no-android)).

**Sendo assim, provavelmente este método que solicita esta `View` faz alterações na tela da aplicação ou mesmo na `View` repassada. Seguindo esta lógica, instanciar um objeto `View` não é correto, visto que o mesmo somente será instanciado e não existirá propriamente na tela da aplicação. Se a View não é necessária para o funcionamento do método então não faz sentido passar a mesma por parâmetro.**

A abordagem correta é pegar esta View na tela da aplicação e repassar ela para o método utilizando o método `findViewById` e pegar o elemento da tela que é referente à este método.

Para pegar o elemento da tela, utilize o `id` que foi utilizado na criação do elemento no `XML` da `Activity`, abaixo um exemplo de como isso deve ser feito:

```
View viewNaTela = findViewById(R.id.elementoNaTela);
lista(viewNaTela);
```

Comment: Poderia postar como `pegar o elemento da tela que é referente à este método.` ? Se faço isso no método, porque no `onCreate` a View da Activity já existirá ?

Comment: Resposta editada.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, o método exige ter a `View`, por exemplo o Toast. Não é que ele exige elementos, mas a chamada de um objeto view.

Comment: `Toast` não exige uma `View` e sim um `Context` vide a documentação do Toast: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html, vc pode ver que no exemplo que você postou a váriável `v` não é utilizada em momento algum

Comment: Entendi. E no caso de um `Button` que chama o método ? Se o método não tiver a View, encerra a aplicação...

Comment: Não estou entendendo a sua dúvida, criei a conversa de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72546/room-for-julio-borges-and-rbz vamos continuar por lá

Answer (score 2):

Suponho que esse método seja usado por um Button cujo *click listener* tenha sido atribuído, na sua declaração no xml, com `android:onClick=lista`.

Parece que quer que este método seja chamado não só quando clicar no botão mas também pelo seu código.

Em situações destas o habitual é ter um método privado com o código que quer que seja executado em ambas as situações. Esse método é chamado pelo método `lista()` quando o botão é clicado e directamente no outro caso(seu código).

Seria algo assim:

```
public void lista(View v) {
      doListaClick();
}

private void doListaClick(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

No `onCreate()` seria assim:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        doListaClick();
}
```

Como vê não é necessário utilizar ou "inventar" qualquer view para executar o código que pretende.

Comment: Entendi ramaral ! Mas esse processo de separar os 2 métodos seria boa prática, melhor desempenho, segurança ? Ou poderia chamar com o "null" `doListaClick(null);` ?

Comment: Melhor desempenho? Nada de relevante. Melhor prática? Julgo que sim. Passar *null* como argumento normalmente denota "gambiarra". `null` é (talvez) [o pior erro da ciência da computação](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2015/08/31/the-worst-mistake-of-computer-science/). O próprio [Tony Hoare pede desculpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions) por causa disso.